# creating a set of formulas to add a variable sum in excel

Tags: excel-formula

We have a staffing spreadsheet that needs to have a variable equation based in each shift that might deviate from the agreed staffing base.

I want to calculate the sum written in text in column N and output it in column Q. I can't add any other columns to the spreadsheet.

I have written a code using TEXTSPLIT (below) to correctly count the addition but can't get the same formula to subtract the totals.

`=SUM(VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(N8,"+")))`

| row | column N | column Q (current result of formula) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **8** | 3 | 3 |
| **9** | 3+1 | 4 |
| **10** | 3-1 | 44986 |

The results of row 8 & 9 are good, but row 10 changes into a date code.

I have tried the - in the textsplit equation but can't make it work.

Comment: You should post the formula you are having trouble with.  Maybe some sample data also.  Images don't help at all.  They are fuzzy and you can't copy and paste anything.  If you really want help you need to post more information.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way in Office 365:

In the name manager create a name: `EVAL`

and use `refers to`: `=LAMBDA(string,EVALUATE(string))`

Then in Excel type `=EVAL(N2)` or for the range at once: `=EVAL(N2:N4)`

Some companies block the use of this (this requires the workbook to be saved as macro enabled workbook).

In that case you could use:
`=LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(N2,{"+","-"}),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",N2)),SUM(t*{1,-1}),SUM(--t)))`

If there could be multiple numbers and a mix of `+` and `-` signs in the same string you could use:

```
=LET(string,N2,
     num,--TEXTSPLIT(string,{"+","-"}),
     char,TEXTSPLIT("+"&string,SEQUENCE(10)-1,,1),
REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(COUNT(num)),LAMBDA(tempsum,pos,LET(number,INDEX(num,pos),tempsum+IF(INDEX(char,pos)="+",number,-number)))))
```