Use text in the Excel formula to get output
I am trying to put a text value in  the excel formula to calculate the value. For Example,



A
B




5+5
10


20/100
20%



I want the value in the Column B to be produced from a formula such as
=CONCAT("=",A2)*100
or
=INDIRECT(A1)*100
But nothing seem to work

You can do the opposite with =FORMULATEXT(): write 5+5 in B1, in A1 use `=FORMULATEXT(B1), I'm not sure if there's an opposite way (like you want), without VBA.

Excel usually cannot dynamically evaluate text strings as formulas within cells, so you would have to create a custom function using VBA

You could create a Named formula:  =EVALUATE(A1)

This article on superuser asks for the same and has a short answer.

https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-12-secret-evaluate-function  < an explanation of using EVALUATE as a named formula.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77530678/12634230

@DarrenBartrup-Cook: this fails for any cell references within text to evaluate.  VB simply won't know what 'A2' means in the text A2+A3 for instance.  It would require Range('a2').value to understand what A2 refers to.... I've tested to verify. See the example given in soln: =1/2 & " some text" (no references to other cells).  Although arguably this wasn't an explicit requirement nor one of the egs. in PO post. If not then I completely agree- this and the links provided are best / expedient soln.  Nice feature to be able to reference though - hence proposed soln.  ta

@P.b won't handle 20/100. Anything more sophisticated that addition/subtraction (multiple occurrences?) would fail (it's a great solution otherwise).

Below/here refers.
Create this VB function (see: how?*):
Function solve(a_ As Range) As Variant
    t_ = "=" & a_.Value
    Set r_ = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    r_.Global = True
    'r_.Pattern = "([A-Za-z]{1,3}\d+)" 
    r_.Pattern = "((('[^']+')|([A-Za-z0-9]+))!)?([A-Za-z]{1,3}\d+)"
    Set m_ = r_.Execute(t_)
    For Each m In m_
        t_ = Replace(t_, m.Value, Range(m.Value).Value)
    Next
    solve = Evaluate(t_)
End Function


Functionality:

independent calculations:
direct references (within ActiveSheet)
local workbook references (within ActiveWorkbook)






Limitations

Unable to resolve cell references to external workbooks.
Named ranges: remain untested.


Caveats/references

For more robust cell referencing including named ranges and external workbooks, see solns to this* Q by @Kuyenda


Notes link rot mitigated via archived webpage references

̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿’̿’\̵͇̿̿\З= ( ▀ ͜͞ʖ▀) =Ε/̵͇̿̿/’̿’̿ ̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿
